# Firebase document read optimization

Tags: firebase, google-maps, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase firestore for my react-native app, I'm creating a app that will send user geolocation to firestore and generate heatmap, and the app will send user's location every 5 mins, my data looks like this

[image]

Right now I have about 1000 documents, every time I refresh the app, it will try to fetch all coords to generate the heatmap.

The problem I'm having is when it generate the heatmap, it will need to read all 1000 documents, what if I have 5000 coords/documents, and I have 10 users to use it, it will reach the documents read limit in firebase free plan which is 50k/day.

I know I can pay some money to increase the read limit, but just wondering if any one run into this and find optimize way to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you only interested in coordinates that have changed since the last time the heatmap was refreshed? Also, why are you force-refreshing your data.. what if it's static for hours? Wouldn't it be better to just observe for changed nodes and let the data be updated only when needed?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, I found this today https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots, even think probably should add this to cloud function, it will reduce the read even more

Comment: @YiZhou Actually it is not really recommended to use a listener (i.e. onSnapshot) **in a Cloud Function** since it’s life duration is usually vey short.

Comment: I'm using this right now https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all the constraints of your application, but you could possibly store all the coordinates of one month in one document, in an array, reducing by 8928 the number of document reads.

If I did the maths corrrecly, based on this documentation page https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size which explains the Storage size calculations, you can calculate that a doc with 3 arrays named `lat`, `long` and `ts` under your `coords` collection which stores the data for 288*31 triplet values (288 = every 5 minutes in one day) will have a size of maximum 857,088 bytes, which is under the maximum possible size for a document (i.e. 1,048,576 bytes) as presented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Of course, you'll have to deal with the array fields but for that you can use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion();`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: @Yi Zhou Hi, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?